# Change C# app.config appSettings at runtime

Tags: c#, app-config

My app.config has appSettings like that:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="PdfSavePath" value="D:/Test" />
</appSettings>
```

Now i would like to change the PdfSavePath at runtime in my WPF application. When the user selects the path, it should also be updated in the app.config. I tried to do it like that (SavePath contains the new path):

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PdfSavePath"] = SavePath;
```

However, this didn't work. Does anybody have a solution for that?

Comment: A better solution would be to use a `.settings` file instead.

Comment: Did you look at the [`ConfigurationManager` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager)?  The examples show how to add or modify an app setting.